# Ce que c’est que

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I’ve been seeing this construction in several oldish texts, for example in Nerval’s Faust:

> Je te donnerai le conseil court et bon d’en faire autant, afin de pouvoir, affranchi de tes chaînes, goûter *ce que c’est que la vie*.

To my naive mind that just sounds pleonastic, compared with « gouter ce qu’est la vie ». Why the extra stammer?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that this is a pleonastic form if considered to the letter, but in this particular case this pleonasm becomes a marker.
In the chosen instance, the verb "gouter" is found, but it is nothing else than one of several possibilities among which can be found "apprendre" and "savoir"; here is the definition found in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir) concerning savoir.

- Savoir ***ce que c'est que*** (qqc.), que (de + inf.) et, absol., savoir ce que c'est (!) Avoir éprouvé, expérimenté, souvent à ses dépens. V. ce1ex. 16.À la forme nég. Ne pas savoir ce que c'est que (p. euphém., pour exprimer l'intensité de qqc.). N'avoir quasiment jamais éprouvé, subi ou ne pas subir habituellement. Vous ne savez pas ce que c'est que d'être gardien d'un feu aux îles Farsan! (...) Il n'y a au milieu qu'un chenal

Therefore, there is a difference insofar as it is not a matter of plain definition of the thing to be reckoned with but specifically a matter of having the consciousness of it through learning it by being involved in it,  getting a taste of it through real experience.

- … gouter la vie à travers des expériences personnelles de la vie

Answer (score 3):

Until the 17th century the form

> ***Que c'est que...***

was commonly used to say "**what ... is**"; e.g.:

> *Scavez-vous **que c'est que** le monastère ?* - Do you know what the monastery is?

*Les œuvres de messire François de Sales, Évêque et Prince de Genève*, 1619.

Then, a ***ce*** was more and more prepended leading to the still common ***ce que c'est que***, thus Nerval's:

> *Goûter **ce que c’est que** la vie*. - Taste what life is.

Here is what wrote Vaugelas in *Remarques sur la langue française*, 1665:

[image]

> *On ne dit plus guère maintenant **que c'est**, comme l'on disait autrefois. On dit, **ce que c'est**. Par exemple, M. de Malherbe dit,**Il n'y a pas de loi qui nous apprenne que c'est que l'ingratitude.** Aujourd'hui l'on dit, **qui nous apprenne ce que c'est que**, etc.*

> We hardly say anymore **que c'est**, as it used to be. We say, **ce que c'est**. For example, Mr. de Malherbe says, **Il n'y a pas de loi qui nous apprenne que c'est que l'ingratitude.** Today we say, **qui nous apprenne ce que c'est que**...

This idiom being a fixed expression, there is no much point in looking for a pleonasm inside it.

Note that ***que c'est que...*** also lead to the interrogative ***qu'est-ce que...?***

Answer (score 2):

You're right to stress the pleonastic character of this idiomatic expression. It comes from the simple question "*Qu'est-ce que c'est?*" probably created because "*Qu'est-ce?*" seemed phonetically too short to be clearly understood as a question. That same question even became "*Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça?*" meanwhile it simply might have been "*Qu'est cela?*".

The fact is that "*Qu'est-ce?*" and "*Qu'est cela?*" though grammatically correct, are practically never used, but always replaced by "*Qu'est-ce que c'est?*" or "*Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça?*"